# RGBD slam on groovy

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-groovy, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run the rgbd slam package provided on open slam website with ROS groovy. The readme file with the package has instructions for diamondback.
I have downloaded the package along with the hogman_minimal library.
I have also edited the manifest.xml file adding  for openni dependency. But now when I run rosdep install rgbdsalm_freiburg, I get error:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource rgbdsalm_freiburg
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

I am sure my RGBD slam package is in the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable because when I do
roscd rgbdslam, I am able to change my directory to rgbdslam folder.

How can I make it work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58205/rgbd-slam-on-groovy/) by [Robetraks](https://answers.ros.org/users/4427/robetraks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you spelled it wrong. It should be rgbdslam_freiburg :)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2